# HomeDrive vs. SystemDrive

Tags: windows, environment-variables

On my computer, these two variables gives the same result:

```
echo %HomeDrive%   -> C:
echo %SystemDrive% -> C:
```

Is there any difference between them?

Reference links are welcome, because it's too easy to say something like "yes, they are the same" just because they are the same on one's particular computer.

Comment: @StevenPenny Here - http://libertyboy.free.fr/computing/reference/envariables/ - `HomeDrive` is described as the drive letter assigned to the volume which contains your user profiles and `SystemDrive` as the drive letter of the volume where Windows is installed. So as I understand, the values of these variables are different only if you somehow installed your User profile on the different drive than the operating system itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Big difference.

The `%systemdrive%` (typically `c:\`) is the partition with the `%systemroot%` (typically Windows) directory.

`%homedrive%` is typically your network root profile directory, in an (Active Directory) Domain, it would reside on a server.

The web links to their expanded descriptions are rich and voluminous, you could easily find more info about them at [Microsoft.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=homedrive%20site%3Amicrosoft.com).

Comment: @johnc.j. Try the google "site:microsoft.com" parameter, it literally seems to search MIcrosoft's site better than their internal Search bar and Bing. The first two results are enlightening on MS Environment Variables.

Comment: *"in an (Active Directory) Domain, it would reside on a server."* It may be better to say *could reside on a server* as this is not the default behavior in an AD domain but instead requires specific configuration.

Comment: I've done a search on Google for `site:microsoft.com HOMEDRIVE` as per the link in this post, and there isn't actually much information on it and its definition. Unlike `SYSTEMDRIVE`, which is pretty well documented.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to @StevenPenny asking for sourced answers: There are surprisingly few such,
and almost none from Microsoft. Below are a few sources.

[**Upgrade to Windows versions that is before Windows 10 is blocked if Users and ProgramData directories are changed**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/relocation-of-users-and-programdata-directories)

One of the few sources by Microsoft:

> %systemdrive% is defined as the drive that contains the Windows directory.

[**HOMEPATH**](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/HOMEPATH)

> On a Microsoft Windows system, the %HOMEPATH% is the name for what
> Unix/Linux users call $HOME. When combined with the %HOMEDRIVE%
> environment variable you get a complete path to the user's home
> directory.
>
> For example, if your username is “JRandom” then your home drive and
> path is probably one of the following:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\JRandom                      (Windows 7 and newer)
> C:\Documents and Settings\JRandom     (XP and older)
> ```

[**Windows environment variables**](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/development/environment-variables/index)

| Variable | Possible value |  | registry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOMEDRIVE | `C:` | The combination of HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH points to a location where personal files should be stored. It might, but needs not to, be the same directory as %USERPROFILE% | `HKCU\Volatile Environment` |
| HOMEPATH | `\Users\Rene` | Rene correpsonds to %USERNAME%. Compare with %USERPROFILE% | `HKCU\Volatile Environment` |

[**PowerShell : About Automatic Variables**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1)

Another Microsoft article that mentions these variables:

> **$HOME**
>
> Contains the full path of the user's home directory. This variable is
> the equivalent of the "$env:homedrive$env:homepath" Windows
> environment variables, typically C:\Users<UserName>.

Comment: The content of the "PowerShell: About Automatic Variables" article has had at least one significant change since this was posted  - it now states: *''Windows can redirect the location of the user's profile. This means that $HOME may not have the same value as "$env:HOMEDRIVE$env:HOMEPATH".''*